Certification Verification Failed for https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble
Since last weekend I've started to receive certificate errors for https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble.
Ign:1 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                 
Ign:3 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                 
Ign:4 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease         
Hit:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease
Hit:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble InRelease                    
Hit:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease  
Ign:2 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:1 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Err:1 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
Err:2 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
Err:3 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
Err:4 https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 130.185.80.122 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


I've already updated my ca_certificates. Also, I've done the trick to replace https with http in the sources file and took it back. The issue persists.
Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?
Thanks!

Are you sure they're an official mirror?   I don't see them on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors (even in Portugal), but maybe I' missing something.   Why not use an official Ubuntu mirror.

I believe I managed it. I got one from the list you provided (from Porto). Thank you so much!

@RafaelBaptista Please post your last comment as an answer to your own question.

Into the Ubuntu Software update "Other Software", remove the problematic mirror, and insert the new one from my Country (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)
